# MIN MAX query with a twist

Tags: sql, date, max, min

I need to get the MIN and MAX dates for volume but I need to group it based on volume and not all the volume of same amount....

Basically, I have daily volume and dates for those daily volume. I need to be able to get the MIN Date as "to" and MAX date as "from" for a set of volume.

Note that the volume can traverse dates and then break and then have a new set of dates for the same volume.

Hopefully the screenshots below do a better job explaining than I can. I know how to do this via code.. but was wondering if the same was possible with SQL.

Please note that the SQL will be called from within an application and I can't insert into a temp table to get my end result data set...

Here is the raw data that I am querying using select *:

[image: [Raw Data]]

Here is what I ultimately want:

[image: [End Result I am Looking For]]

The query that I am running gives me the MIN and MAX for all the occurrences of the volume 1100.  I want it split based on the break between dates as shown in the End result screenshot....

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT daily_volume, MIN(volume_date) AS min_date, MAX(volume_date) AS max_date, ins_num 
FROM daily_volume 
WHERE ins_num = 3854439 
GROUP BY daily_volume, ins_num
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Also, the accepted answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811993/how-do-i-exclude-rows-when-an-incremental-value-starts-over) question could help solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was written for sql server, but it should work for other databases ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b530f/1)):

```
with DatesMinMax as
(
    select 
        volume_date, 
        daily_volume, 
        isnull 
        (
            (
            select top 1 d2.volume_date
            from daily_volume  d2
            where d.volume_date > d2.volume_date and d.daily_volume <> d2.daily_volume
            order by d2.volume_date desc
            )
            , '1753-01-01'
        ) as min_date,
        isnull 
        (
            (
            select top 1 d2.volume_date
            from daily_volume  d2
            where d.volume_date < d2.volume_date and d.daily_volume <> d2.daily_volume
            order by d2.volume_date 
            )
            , '9999-12-31'
        )  as max_date
    from daily_volume  d
),
DatesFromTo as 
(
    select d1.daily_volume as qty, 
        (select min(d2.volume_date) 
         from DatesMinMax d2 
         where d2.volume_date > d1.min_date and d2.volume_date < d1.max_date
        ) as [from],
        (select max(d2.volume_date) 
         from DatesMinMax d2 
         where d2.volume_date > d1.min_date and d2.volume_date < d1.max_date
        ) as [to]
    from DatesMinMax d1
)
select distinct
    qty,
    [from],
    [to]
from DatesFromTo
order by [from]
```

`DatesMinMax` is used to get the first date that had a different volume than the current volume

`DatesFromTo` is used to get the date range for each row

Comment: Aducci, you are a genius.  This worked like a champ!  I had to add an ins_num filter to only return the values I was looking for but it worked.  I also tried the partition method suggested by julien and that worked too.